# XSL Page Break After Completion Of XML

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to convert xml into pdf using xsl for some business requirement(can't share that code here). My requirement is to add a page break after completion of xml reading. Here we are reading that same xml two times and adding that result into a single pdf. For example , after reading the xml for the first time we get a pdf of 2 pages, So on reading the same xml second time , I want my result to start from third page of pdf and not on the second page. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artit>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>       
    </cd>   
</catalog>
```

Say Using loop, I am reading this same xml twice and I want the result of each iteration of loop on separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an `fo:page-sequence` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence) for each `catalog`.  By definition, each `fo:page-sequence` starts a new page.

Alternatively, the second time that you process the XML, add `break-before="page"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#break-before) or `page-break-before="always"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-break-before, and a shorthand for `break-before="page"`) to the FO generated from the appropriate element.

Comment: you mean to say that page sequence will make sure second time we read the xml , it will automatically start from the new page. Am I right ?

Comment: I think that we understand each other.  An `fo:page-sequence` generates pages, but it's hard to say what the best solution to your problem is since you haven't shown any of your XSLT or XSL-FO.